# how to get the data from view to templates?

Tags: html, django, django-2.0

i'm trying to get the data from my views.py to the html page.
if the views.py code is this

```
def VerifiedBySuperuser(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
        vbs = MaanyaIT_EXAM48_ManageQuestionBank()
        vbs.QuestionID = MaanyaIT_EXAM48_ManageQuestionBank.objects.get(QuestionID=request.POST.get(QuestionID, None))
        vbs.QuestionInEnglishLang = request.POST.get('QuestionInEnglishLang', None)
        vbs.save()
else:
        return render(request, 'exam48app/verifiedbysuperuser.html')
```

then what shoud the code of html page to view my all data to the tamplates..

this is my html page

```
<form class="from-horizontal" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="post-entry">
     {{ MaanyaIT_EXAM48_ManageQuestionBank.QuestionInEnglishLang }}
</div>
</form>
```

now  what should i do?

Comment: `return render(request, 'exam48app/verifiedbysuperuser.html', context={"data":yourdata})`

Comment: no no i want to know that what should i wrote in html page so that the data will display in html page.

Comment: You will need to return a context variable in the render function. This context variable(your data) can be used as {{variable_name}} in your html wherever you want to use it.

Comment: see the html page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you need to know How to write/render the data from view to html template
I will demonstrate a simple example for you,
Assuming you have a view as below,

```
def VerifiedBySuperuser(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = {
            "T_Name": "My Name",
            "T_Age": 50,
            "T_Phone": 1478523699
        }
        return render(request, 'verifiedbysuperuser.html', context=context)
```

and a HTML template as follows,

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
    Name : {{ T_Name }}<br>
    Age : {{ T_Age }}<br>
    Phone : {{ T_Phone }}<br>
</body>
</html>
```

When you access your view, you will get a response like this,
[image: Output Image]

In your case, you can pass as many attributes to template as `dict` (shown in my example) and in template/html `keys of context` (that is `T_Name`,`T_Name` etct) becomes variable. So you can directly use them in HTML inside the twin braces (`{{ variable_name }}`)

As far as I knew, this is the general procedure for  `template rendering/ html rendering`

**UPDATE-1**

```
def VerifiedBySuperuser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=some_id)
        other_data = [1,2,3,4,] # some specific data
        context = {
            "post_data": request.data,
            "object_instance": obj,
            "some_other_data": other_data
        }
        return render(request, 'verifiedbysuperuser.html', context=context)
```

Comment: you r right but i wnat to get the data from admin...what shoud i do?

Comment: What you mean by `data from admin` ?

Comment: u directly put the name and show in html, but i want to get name from when i submit name from a form.

Comment: see **UPDATE-1** portion